# How is metadata handled over sequential versions of a document?

Tags: versioning, metadata

I want people to stop putting their name in the file name every time they review a document. As a compromise, I would like to suggest putting their name's in the metadata of that version.
So, my question is: If Jane edits V 0.5 and adds her name to the metadata, and saves creating V 0.6 with her name as a metadata tag. Then Jack edits V 0.6, adds his name to the metadata, and saves, creating V 0.7. 
Will V 0.7 have both of their names in the metadata or only Jack's?

I guess another way to ask this is: Is there a discrete set of metadata for each version of a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Modified By property is updated automatically by SharePoint each time a version is created with the current logged in user.  Looking at the version history will show who edited the document and when.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if this totally answers my question though. If V 0.5 is tagged with Jill's name, will V0.6 be as well or does each version have it's own set of tags?

Comment: Each version has its own tags - but in the version history you can see all of them.